# Use bluetooth to identify application specific data?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am buildind a application in which a user sends a image from bluetooth and when the reciever taps on the notification that image should be opened in that application only.

Comment: So what is your problem? Please describe and post your code as well.!!

Comment: i don't know how to make that notification such that it opens a application and the image sent is displayed in that.